# Is it legal to lie, if the assumption is that you will not lie, in a commercial setting?

Tags: united-states, chatgpt, bing, llm

Today I asked Bing Chat for "the top ten funny movies in the past 20 years."

It responded with (first 4):
Good boys (2019), Stuber (2019), Shazam (2019), When we first met (2018).

I was disturbed that BingGPT gave this answer, as its obviously heavily influenced by whomever is paying them.

I then asked ChatGPT for comparison.

It responded (first 4)
Superbad (2007), The Hangover (2009), Groundhog Day (1993), Anchorman: The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004)

While obviously, one can argue what the top 10 funniest movies are, etc, etc.  Bing chat's answered skewed to what an advertising agency told them to answer, regardless of what basis information the internet provided.

I imagine they run their queries run something like this:

1. "User phrase" is first used to search for any active advertising.
2. Compile a break down of this, and tell ChatGPT to prefer any items in the given list, etc.  Not to say negative characteristics about items in the list, etc.

---

My question is this:
When does this become illegal?  Does it ever become illegal?

For instance, can Bing give me back counterfactual information that endangers me, if an advertiser wanted to sell me, let's say, drug A, even if it was proven harmful.

Can Bing lie to me about things like car fatalities, given a brand they advertise?

Could Bing tell me to take a homeopathic remedy for depression instead of seeking counseling?

Is there any threshold where the lie becomes illegal?

---

Thank you, oh gods of the law.  I look forward to your response.

Comment: LLMs are essentially random word generators. No sane person would believe that anything generated by an LLM is in any way, shape, or form, factual or true.

Comment: I wonder if I am being downvoted, because it is somehow a "bad question" or if Bing has their PR team operating on stackoverflow as well.

Comment: Wonder no more, it is the former.

Comment: @MichaelHall Lol.  I wonder if it illegal to remove information regarding Tiananmen Square, or Nazi concentration camps from search results.  If bing claimed they did not exist, no matter how I asked for them (and I asked many different ways to get a true movie listing), if Bing removed my ability to access this information, without me even knowing they did, if Bing did this in a way so as to "gas-light" the user into believing they were in fact giving answers without bias - all of this is legal?  I find it an interesting question - but I guess it's just me.

Comment: Placing limits on the quantity or type of information you provide is not the same thing as lying, and generally is not illegal.

Comment: @iamacomputer: An LLM has no concept of "facts", "truth", "information", "knowledge", etc. It is just a random word generator that generates "convincingly sounding" text. The purpose of an LLM is *not* to generate *correct* text, it is to generate *convincing* text. All an LLM is, is a big database of which word is statistically likely to follow which other words. It then uses these statistics to string together sentences which *look like* they could be written by a person. That's it. An LLM *cannot* knowingly hide the truth, because it doesn't even know what "the truth" is.

Answer (score 1):

It is [possible for lying in a commercial setting to constitute fraud](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/98242). It seems like in the US the lie has to be material to the commercial relationship.

It is unreasonable (but common) to assume that a text generator like Bing Chat will not lie. It does in fact spit out things that are not true on a regular basis, and people keep trying to tell the general public this. If a system like this is marketed as if it reliably tells the truth, that marketing is misleading and might violate applicable laws about misleading marketing. If it induces reliance on something not actually reliable, and something goes wrong, the person harmed could sue for damages. (But any consciencable provisions of Bing Chat's contract [would apply](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/98268).)

But the real thrust of your question seems to be along the lines of "would it be legal to market an AI chatbot service as if it were a fiduciary designed to act in the user's best interest, while actually subborning it and instructing it to manipulate the user into e.g. buying particular products?". I'm not sure that the law has caught up to that particular question, so the applicable laws would be about false advertising and deceptive trade practices in general. I am not sure that the law addresses fiduciary duties of non-human systems, or whether they can be agents of corporations so that their false statements are attributable to the corporation.

These might be good topics to call your local lawmakers about.

Answer (score -1):

The Bing TOS contains a sufficient disclaimer (§9), so that they would not be liable for any harm resulting from responses. It should also be noted that "lie" refers to a particular mental state, which a program lacks. There is some possibility that they could be found liable for copyright infringement, a point which has been discussed inconclusively here (inconclusive because of insufficient facts). In fact, a user would be more likely to be founds to be negligent in relying unreasonably on Bing AI output, in the same way that a person who jumped off a bridge would be found negligent in relying on the say-so of an insane passer-by that "If you jump off this bridge, you will fly" (thus defeating a lawsuit against the insane person for negligently giving bad advice).

Comment: Interesting.. BTW, I did not downvote you.  I'm not sure why someone would downvote your answer.  It seems reasonable.

Comment: what does §9 refer to?

Comment: I see, the current TOS 9: No Guarantees; No Representations or Warranties; Indemnification by You. We plan to continue to develop and improve the Online Services, but we make no guarantees or promises about how the Online Services operate or that they will function as intended. The Online Services are for entertainment purposes; the Online Services are not error-free, may not work as expected and may generate incorrect information. You should not rely on the Online Services and you should not use the Online Services for advice of any kind. Your use of the Online Services is at your own risk.

Comment: Actually I want to take issue with one part of your answer, "It should also be noted that "lie" refers to a particular mental state, which a program lacks."

If a company directs an employee to answer in a certain way, which is a lie - even though the employee has no lying mental state, does not he still propagate lies?

Comment: How could you repeat a lie and NOT be in a lying mental state?

Comment: @MichaelHall If someone tells me a lie and I believe it, and then repeat it.

Comment: @iamacomputer: But an LLM just randomly generates text. It has no concept of "facts" or "truth". It just randomly strings words together in a way that is statistically likely to generate semi-coherent sounding text. Nothing more. It *cannot* "lie", i.e., knowingly convey untrue facts, because it has no concept of *knowing*, *truth*, or *facts*.